# Developing Slowly Changing Dimension in SSAS

Tags: ssas, scd

I searched the internet a lot but nothing good came of it. I have 3 table and want to develop SCD type 2 in SSAS Cube.

1- DimCompanies

2- DimDate

3- FactTable

FactTable:

Val

CompanyId

DateId

[image]

DimCompanies has this information :

CompanyId

CompanyName

[image]

I used many methods on the internet, such as adding the Surrogate key and bussiness Key, but to no avail.

My question is that a company has a name for a year, for example 2000 to 2005, and after 2006 it has a new name. Therefore, new information must be displayed when the cube is loaded, but whatever I do, this mode can not be implemented. I add YearId and IsCurrent In DimCompanies But I dont know how to use it. I also do not know how to connect the DimDate to the DimCompanies.

Answer (score 0):

your DimDate and DimCompanies should have an unique key (primary Key) which will link to your Fact Table columns DateId and CompaniesId (Foreign Keys) - This is how you will connect the two as they are already connected in the fact table.

Comment: Thanks joe. but i want to create SCD or slowly changing dimension on Fact not regular connection